# Name for combo box with substring filter?

Tags: terminology, controls

What do you call a combobox in which what you write in the combobox filters a (long) list that can be accessed as a dropdown menu.

Here we filter with the strings `igh`, `s`, and not `old`; so any line that does not contain `old` but which contains `igh` and `s` in any order anywhere in the line is displayed in the list, and lines not containing both `igh`and `s` or `old` are ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you would still call that a combobox, because the term refers to the UI element and the information that it displays.

The feature you are talking about is like an auto-suggest or smart search (or perhaps there is another term for it) that you can implement in a combobox for input and filtering.